# ng-repeat not updated inside bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just take a simple array and there is add more button in which i just push one more object to that array.
The array is ng-repeat which renders all the fields. My code are given below.

```
<div ng-init="core.iv=[{email:'',name:''}];">
  <div ng-repeat="n in core.iv track by $index">
    <div class="col-sm-6 pad0">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control mIn" ng-model="n.email" placeholder="Email id" />
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 pad0">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control mIn" ng-model="n.name" placeholder="Name" />
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 pad0 text-right">
    <button class="btn btn-t-primary btn-sm" ng- click="core.iv.push({email:'',name:''});">add more</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you please make a plunker

Comment: Remove space for 'ng- click'. It should be **ng-click**

Comment: There is no space in between ng-click in my code.

Comment: ng-model also not updating

Comment: Off the top of my head now, and I'm not sure what Bootstrap does with the dialog element. But if it makes a copy of the element and puts it somewhere else in the DOM it would loose the angular scope.

Comment: Tried it in a plunker, it seems to work ok. https://plnkr.co/NFoSIW2Y6Nx0N2quYXSq